# Mongoose validation giving "CastError: Cast to undefined failed for value"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I am trying to save the data in database, it's giving forbidden message

**CastError: Cast to undefined failed for value**

```
[
   {"product":{"supplierId":{"undefined":"rfytr"}}},
   {"product":{"supplierId":{"$empty":"rfytr"}}}
] at path "condition"
```

I am unable to figure out the problem. 
My Schema is

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    validator = require('mongoose-validators'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var RuleSchema = new Schema({
     description: {
        type: String,
        validate: [validator.isLength(1, 50)]
    },

    status: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['live', 'active', 'paused', 'inactive', 'unfinished']
    },

    /** 
      condition. It can only contain object.
    */
    condition: [{
        type: Object
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce that exact error, but you should change the definition of `condition` in your schema to be one of the supported formats for an array of unstructured objects as I was getting other errors trying to use `[{type: Object}]`. Either of these work:

```
condition: [{}]
condition: [Schema.Types.Mixed]
```

But you'll also need to remove the leading `$` on the `$empty` field name as field names that start with a `$` [aren't allowed](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names) by MongoDB.